# Windows Phone 8 app throws exception when user tries to buy something

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that allows for in-app purchases. When a user clicks the "buy" button, I have the following code:

```
try {
  ProductListing product = GetProductToBuy();
  MessageBox.Show("Product retrieved.");
  var boughtProduct = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(product.ProductId, true);
  MessageBox.Show(product.ProductId + " was purchased.");
} catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().FullName + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.HResult);
}
```

When I execute this code, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown. The message associated with the exception simply says:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The HResult value is -2146233079

Why am I getting an `InvalidOperationException` without any additional information? I am running the app on an actual device instead of the emulator. I'm really confused.

Thank you

Comment: Where does the debugger say the error is?

Comment: what line of code fails? What is the code for GetProductToBuy?

Answer (score 0):

Run the app in the emulator - my best guess would be that since your app is not in the store, it cannot recognize the item you are trying to purchase, since your device is bound to an actual Microsoft account.

More details on testing in-app purchases are available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same issue and error message when I am running the app on a device on a beta application.

What I did was to resubmit a new beta application to get the new App ID, recreate the in-app purchases, and everything works fine without having to change the code. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call ReportProductFulfillment of all previous purchases?

Windows Phone only. Notifies the marketplace that the application has delivered the paid-for goods to the user. You cannot repurchase a product until you have confirmed its delivery using this method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.reportproductfulfillment.aspx

Try this:

```
foreach (var i in CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses) { 
    CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(i.Value.ProductId);
}
```